# can we create a CDN without domain name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cdn

I want to create a CDN network without purchasing any domain name, I have Amazon server and i 've installed S3 on that server.

Please tell me is it possible to create CDN without domain name, can we create on IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create distribution using Amazon CloudFront, you can:

- Store objects in one Amazon S3 bucket.
- Distribute download content such as text or graphics.
- Make your objects accessible to everyone.
- **Using Amazon CloudFront domain name in URLs for your objects** (for example, http://d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net/image.jpg) **instead of your own domain name** (for example, http://www.example.com/image.jpg).
- CloudFront edge locations, keep your objects into the default duration of 24 hours for fast content delivery.

If you want to access data using your own domain name (http://www.example.com) then :

- You add a CNAME for www.example.com to your distribution, you also need to create (or update) a CNAME record with your DNS service to route queries for www.example.com to d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net.
- You must have permission to create a CNAME record with the DNS service provider for the domain. **Typically, this means that you own the domain, but you may also be developing an application for the domain owner**.

Reference : [Amazon CloudFront](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Introduction.html) and [CloudFront Introduction](http://www.bucketexplorer.com/documentation/cloudfront--amazon-cloudfront-introduction.html)